# Node js последовательность выполнения

Tags: node.js

```js
function onSignin(post_obj) {
  if ((post_obj.email.length > 0) && (post_obj.pass.length > 0))
    {
      db_check_user_1_log_2_pass(post_obj.email, post_obj.pass).then(  new Promise(function (arg) {
          assert.equal(arg[0].pass, post_obj.pass);
          return true
      }) )

    }
  else {
    console.log('invalid post');
    return false
  }
}
```

```js
function onSignin(post_obj) {
  if ((post_obj.email.length > 0) && (post_obj.pass.length > 0))
    {
      db_check_user_1_log_2_pass(post_obj.email, post_obj.pass).then(function (arg) {
          assert.equal(arg[0].pass, post_obj.pass)
          console.log('asd');
          return true;
      })

    }
  else {
    console.log('invalid post');
    return false
  }



}



console.log( onSignin(post_obj) );
```

Почему эти строки выполняются в таком порядке? Это из-за асинхронности? Как тогда их выполнить правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рабочий пример кода в текстовом виде приведите. Картинку можно оставить

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Второй вариант кода с Promise ругается на Cannot read property 'pass' of undefined

Comment: "Почему эти строки выполняются в таком порядке?" - как Вы это выяснили